# My btn_enter doesn't works after it gets clicked. What am I doing wrong. I want it to work only three times and after that it should stop working

Tags: tkinter, button

Lottery function

```
# imported modules
from tkinter import *
import smtplib
import random
```

root window

```
# creating window
root= Tk()
root.geometry("650x450")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.title("Tiffin Seva")
root.configure(bg="Light blue")
```

variables
# variables
var1 = StringVar()
var_email = StringVar()
var_email2 = StringVar()

Email receiver entry field

```
user_email = Entry(root,textvariable=var_email, width=40)
lb_mail = Label(root, text="Enter your Email address below.", bg="light blue")
user_email.place(x=200,y=50)
lb_mail.place(x=200,y=10)
```

defined functions
#defining functions
def inbox():
box = Listbox(root,bg="light blue", bd=10, height=15)
box.place(x=300,y=0)

```
def ask():

    try:

        if var_email.get() == "":
            lb_mail.destroy()
            user_email.destroy()
            btn_enter.destroy()
            user_email2 = Entry(root, textvariable=var_email2, width=40, 
bd=5,bg="red")
            lb_mail2 = Label(root, text="You didn't typed your email 1 try 
left.",bg="red")
            user_email2.place(x=200, y=35)
            lb_mail2.place(x=200, y=10)
```

this question is not being posted it is saying please add some more details.

```
        else:



            def start():

            

                btn_enter.destroy()

                btn_start.destroy()
                lucky_number = random.randint(4000, 5000)
                print(lucky_number)
                email = "dahiyamohit2007@gmail.com"
                password = "Mohit@2007"

                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(f'{email}', f'{password}')
                print("login successful")

                server.sendmail(f'{email}',
                                f'{user_email.get()}',
                                f"{lucky_number}" + str(",This is your 
lottery spin number."))
                print("message sent successfully")

                lbe = Label(root, text="Enter the lucky number you got in your email")
                lbe.place(x=200, y=170)
                E = Entry(root, textvariable=var1, width=40)
                E.place(x=200, y=200)

            btn_start = Button(root, text="Start The lottery!", bg="gold", 
fg="black", font=("arial", 30), command=start)
            btn_start.place(x=170, y=300)



    except:
        if smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            l = Label(root, text="There is an error couldn't start your lottery.")
            l.place(x=170,y=350)
```

This button is one I want to fix.
When the user types nothing in the in the entry field then it should work again.

```
btn_enter = Button(root,text="Enter", bg="gold", fg="black", font=("arial", 30)
               , command=ask)
btn_enter.place(x=200,y=300)
```

mainloop

```
root.mainloop()
```

Please fix this button.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: could You also please reduce Your code to [mre]. Also don't post text in between Your code

Comment: I will remember to do this in future.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand your code you haven't gave any error details and other stuff but as I understand, In the top of `ask` function you should check if user clicked button 3 times or not. Here's the idea.

```
times=0
def ask():
    global times
    times+=1
    if times<=3:
        #Here all other things you have done
```

In this way `times` will count how many times user clicked in button and check if it is less then 3 or not.